# event list calendar system

Tags: php, events, calendar

I am looking for a place to even start this issue.  I am looking for a code, or a starting place, where I can dynamically have an event calendar.  I would like for it to display 3 month at a time, this month, next month, and the following.  I could do this using the date function.  the issue I have is the when the correct year will come in.  so in december, it displays dec 2013, jan 2014, feb 2014.  I could make it so that it restarts at jan 2013.  then I also need an area to display events that are pulled from a database.  can anyone help me get started?  or direct me somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you need.

If you need an event calendar a simple google search for php calendar script would get you to many starting points.

If you are looking for a way to circularly roll a calendar within a single year I would suggest one of the following.

Depending on how the particular calendar code is set up you could subtract a year from the seed date. For instance...

Before any month is rendered check the year and subtract.

```
$currentStartOfNextMonthSeed = '2014-01-01';
$date = strtotime($currentStartOfNextYearSeed . ' -1 year');
```

Or just change the year to the current year using a regexp.

Since you haven't provided a specific example, a specific answer is not possible. But you did ask for a starting point, hope this helps.

Good luck

Tim

Tim@mpact-media.com